# Invalid \escape in json.loads(), python 2.7

Tags: python, json, io, character-encoding

I am having a list of jsons in a text file as

```
[{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"},{},{}]
```

Now I am trying to read the file and converting it into list of dicts so that I can iterate and use those key-value pairs using code -

```
with open('./file.txt') as f:
   listOfDict= json.load(f)
```

I am getting error -

```
ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 2005707 (char 2005706)
```

I think that might be because some of the values are like - 
For eg. {"key1":"ENERGIZER\xc2"}

**I forgot to use text.encode("utf-8") while writing to this file.**
Instead I used str(text) while writing to the file.

Is this is the reason for this error and how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: @DanielG Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you'll have to do a little string manipulation to unescape and decode.

It depends on whether your data contains escaped Unicodes or escaped 8bit characterset, like `latin1` or `cp1252`. You'll have to experiment to see what works for your data.

If it's escaped Unicode you can simply do:

```
import io
with io.open('./file.txt', 'r', encoding='unicode_escape') as f:
    listOfDict= json.load(f)
```

If escaped 8bit 'latin1', you'll need to do:

```
with open('./file.txt', 'r') as f:
    # read, convert escape to byte, convert bytes as 'latin1'
    decoded_json = f.read().decode('string_escape').decode('latin1')
    listOfDict = json.loads(decoded_json) # Note the "s".
```

Comment: What does str.decode('string_escape') function do? I am having urls in the text file, like "https://" does that gonna affect those too, please also tell, what I had missed out while saving the text file, since I am getting these errors.

Comment: `string_escape` works on just backslashes. `text.encode("utf-8")` wouldn't have fixed your data - something else is at play - you probably saved the `repr()` of the string by mistake